# Can't implement struct with 2-d array in it in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

For example I have the following 2 structs in C:

```
typedef struct {
    int index[128][128];
    int value;
} x;

typedef struct {
    x allx[128];
} y;
```

And in the main function I'm trying to use them:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    x x1 = {{{1,2},{3,4}}, 1};
    x x2 = {{{2,4},{1,5}}, 0};
    x x3 = {{{3,6},{1,7}}, 1};

    y y1 = {{x1,x2,x3}};

    printf("%s\n", "Test");
}
```

However, after I compile and run it, nothing happens. The printf is to test if the program work can run. But it just does nothing, never prints the "Test". And during the compile, no error happens. I don't know if it's the problem of the 2-d array in the struct x. Anyone can help?

Comment: Try running in a debugger and see what happens.

Comment: Assuming a 32bit `int`, you're requesting roughly 196608 bytes for the three `x` instances (64k each), and an added 8388608 bytes for that `y` instance. In total, roughly 8.1875 **MB** of automatic storage. If your runtime setup doesn't play well with that, you're program will essentially puke on itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely stack overflow.  A single y on the stack is 128*128*4*128 which is 8 meg.  On windows the default stack is 1 meg (or it used to be) and linux is like 8 meg I think.

When I shrink y to

```
typedef struct {
    x allx[8];
} y;
```

Or make the variables static, it runs fine on Xcode.

Comment: Thank you! That's the reason. It really helps.